# Best 3D PDF exporter for Inventor

Tags: pdf, 3d, pdf-generation, autodesk-inventor

I am using Inventor to create models. I am searching a 3DPDF exporter plugin to export 3DPDF file. I need a exporter that can export 3D PDF file with color and geometry.

I am searching a 3d PDF exporter that Best 3DPDF file.

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is off-topic. On the one hand because "Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.", but secondly asking for recommendations for tools is *also* off-topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many 3dpdf exporter available in market and I am using one of them from last 6 month. It exports model to pdf as you have in inventor with colors and accurate geometry shape.

Trial version of it also available  at : http://prototechsolutions.com/Live/3DPDFApplications.html

I ended up my searching after this exporter and it worked for me.